# How to convert bgra8Unorm iOS-Metal texture to rgba8Unorm texture?

Tags: ios, swift, textures, gpu, metal

I am working with iOS 11, XCode 9 and Metal 2. I have a `MTLTexture` with pixel format `bgra8Unorm`. I cannot change this pixel format, because according to [pixelFormat documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/1478155-pixelformat):

> The pixel format for a Metal layer must be bgra8Unorm, bgra8Unorm_srgb, rgba16Float, BGRA10_XR, or bgra10_XR_sRGB.

The other pixel formats are not suitable for my application.

Now I want to create an `UIImage` from the texture. I am able to do so by extracting the pixel bytes from the texture ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1516318-getbytes)):

```
getBytes(_:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage:from:mipmapLevel:slice:)
```

I am processing these bytes to get an `UIImage`:

```
func getUIImageForRGBAData(data: Data) -> UIImage? {
    let d = (data as NSData)

    let width = GlobalConfiguration.textureWidth
    let height = GlobalConfiguration.textureHeight
    let rowBytes = width * 4
    let size = rowBytes * height

    let pointer = malloc(size)
    memcpy(pointer, d.bytes, d.length)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: pointer, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!

    let imgRef = context.makeImage()
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: imgRef!)
    return image
}
```

However, CGContext assumes that the pixels are in the rgba8 format. For example, red texture pixels are blue in the final UIImage. Is there a way to change the pixelFormat in this process to get the proper colors?

Comment: Have you checked Accelerate framework methods? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/conversion

Comment: You're allowed to use textures other than those of the Metal layer, you know. Just because that restriction exists doesn't mean you can't draw to a texture of a different format, either in parallel to drawing to the drawable's texture or in sequence (draw to your texture first, then draw that texture to the drawable's texture).

Comment: Thanks for the hints, will try it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function will swizzle the bytes of a `.bgra8Unorm` texture into RGBA order and create a `UIImage` from the data:

```
func makeImage(from texture: MTLTexture) -> UIImage? {
    let width = texture.width
    let height = texture.height
    let bytesPerRow = width * 4

    let data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: bytesPerRow * height, alignedTo: 4)
    defer {
        data.deallocate(bytes: bytesPerRow * height, alignedTo: 4)
    }

    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)
    texture.getBytes(data, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)

    var buffer = vImage_Buffer(data: data, height: UInt(height), width: UInt(width), rowBytes: bytesPerRow)

    let map: [UInt8] = [2, 1, 0, 3]
    vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(&buffer, &buffer, map, 0)

    guard let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.genericRGBLinear) else { return nil }
    guard let context = CGContext(data: data, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                  space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue) else { return nil }
    guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else { return nil }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

**Caveat**: This function is very expensive. Creating an image from a Metal texture every frame is almost never what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! Almost exactly the way I solved it in the meantime. This function is just used to export a texture, so it is definitely not used every frame.